# How can I use TestActivity inherited Activity in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to use TestActivity, which inherited Activity, in AFragment and use it in one screen with another BFragment, but it seems impossible.
In this case, is there any other way other than re-implementing TestActivity as a Fragment?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve?